# Spark Structured streaming with Java - unable to read from socket

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, spark-structured-streaming

My structured streaming application is trying to read from socket.

```
        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()                
            .appName("trialapp")
            .master("local")
            .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> lines = sparkSession.readStream().format("socket")
            .option("host", "localhost")
            .option("port", "1234")
            .load();

    System.out.println("streaming source ready : " + lines.isStreaming());

            lines.writeStream()
            .outputMode("append") 
            .format("console")
            .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000))
            .start()
            .awaitTermination();
```

I am running this on a windows machine. I am sending messages to port 1234 using ncat command.

[image]

When I run the program, the logs repeatedly say theres no incoming messages

[image]

I have a ncat listener running in parallel listening to the same port and that one is receiving messages

[image]

Why is my Spark program not able to read the messages?